# Write Author names in all CAPS - but only if it is a person

Tags: biblatex, biber, scrartcl

Environment: scrartcl, biblatex with biber backend, style authortitle with some modifications

My educational institution requires me to write the last names of every author in CAPS. To do this, I used DeclareNameFormat and `\MakeUppercase`.

```
\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
  \nameparts{#1}%
  \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
    {\MakeUppercase{\namepartfamily}}
    {\namepartgiven}
    {\namepartprefix}
    {\namepartsuffix}%
}
```

This has the side effect, that company names are written in CAPS too, even when put in double curly braces.
How can I change this behaviour in some way that allows me to write only "normal" author names in CAPS without changing the document class or bibliography style?

Examples for bibliography entries:

```
@misc{rfc4025,
series =    {Request for Comments},
number =    4025,
howpublished =  {RFC 4025},
publisher = {RFC Editor},
doi =       {10.17487/RFC4025},
url =       {https://rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4025.txt},
author =    {Michael Richardson},
title =     {{A Method for Storing IPsec Keying Material in DNS}},
pagetotal = 12,
date =      2005,
month =     mar,
urldate = {2021-09-29},
}
```

The one above works and generates `RICHARDSON, Michael: A Method for Storing IPsec Keying Material in DNS, [...]`

```
@misc{corporate,
title = {A title},
author = {{The Company}},
url = {https://example.org},
urldate = {2021-10-01},
}
```

This one generates something like `THE COMPANY: A title, [...]`

Comment: Welcome. Nice profile pic.

Comment: Can you give examples of the relevant bib entries, to show how you store this information?

Comment: @AndrewSwann I added examples as requested.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can test whether the family name is present, which it is not with a corporate author.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{rfc4025,
series =    {Request for Comments},
number =    4025,
howpublished =  {RFC 4025},
publisher = {RFC Editor},
doi =       {10.17487/RFC4025},
url =       {https://rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4025.txt},
author =    {Michael Richardson},
title =     {{A Method for Storing IPsec Keying Material in DNS}},
pagetotal = 12,
date =      2005,
month =     mar,
urldate = {2021-09-29},
}

@misc{corporate,
title = {A title},
author = {{The Company}},
url = {https://example.org},
urldate = {2021-10-01},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
  \nameparts{#1}%
  \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
    {\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\namepartgiven}
       {\namepartfamily}% no family name, don't uppercase
       {\MakeUppercase{\namepartfamily}}%
    }
    {\namepartgiven}
    {\namepartprefix}
    {\namepartsuffix}%
}

\begin{document}

\cite{rfc4025} and \cite{corporate}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

I think it is slightly more natural to build the logic into the command that actually formats the family name (`\mkbibnamefamily`) instead of passing the actual name part to the uppercasing macro before sending it off to the `biblatex` formatting macros.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \ifdefvoid{\namepartgiven}
    {#1}
    {\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{rfc4025,
  series       = {Request for Comments},
  number       = 4025,
  howpublished = {RFC 4025},
  publisher    = {RFC Editor},
  doi          = {10.17487/RFC4025},
  url          = {https://rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4025.txt},
  author       = {Michael Richardson},
  title        = {A Method for Storing {IPsec} Keying Material in {DNS}},
  pagetotal    = 12,
  date         = 2005,
  month        = mar,
  urldate      = {2021-09-29},
}
@misc{corporate,
  title   = {A title},
  author  = {{The Company}},
  url     = {https://example.org},
  urldate = {2021-10-01},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{rfc4025} and \cite{corporate}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [1] RICHARDSON, Michael. A Method for Storing IPsec Keying Material in DNS. RFC 4025. Mar. 2005. doi: 10.17487/RFC4025. url: https://rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4025.txt (visited on 09/29/2021). [2] The Company. A title. url: https://example.org (visited on 10/01/2021).]

---

Strictly speaking the definition shown above is slightly unorthodox as `\mkbibnamefamily` should ideally not reference `\namepart...` macros. If we want to avoid that, we need some trickery that makes the code 'a bit' longer.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\newtoggle{bbx:nogivenname}
\renewbibmacro*{name:family-given}[4]{%
  \ifdefvoid{#2}
    {\toggletrue{bbx:nogivenname}}
    {}%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \mkbibcompletenamefamilygiven{%
       \ifdefvoid{#3}
         {}
         {\ifcapital
            {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}
            {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
          \ifprefchar{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
       \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
       \ifdefvoid{#4}
         {}
         {\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}%
       \ifdefvoid{#2}
         {}
         {\revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibcompletenamefamilygiven{%
       \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
       \ifdefvoid{#4}
         {}
         {\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}%
       \ifboolexpe{%
         test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
         and
         test {\ifdefvoid{#3}}}
         {}
         {\revsdnamepunct}%
       \ifdefvoid{#2}
         {}
         {\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}%
       \ifdefvoid{#3}
         {}
         {\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}}}}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:nogivenname}
    {#1}
    {\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{rfc4025,
  series       = {Request for Comments},
  number       = 4025,
  howpublished = {RFC 4025},
  publisher    = {RFC Editor},
  doi          = {10.17487/RFC4025},
  url          = {https://rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4025.txt},
  author       = {Michael Richardson},
  title        = {A Method for Storing {IPsec} Keying Material in {DNS}},
  pagetotal    = 12,
  date         = 2005,
  month        = mar,
  urldate      = {2021-09-29},
}
@misc{corporate,
  title   = {A title},
  author  = {{The Company}},
  url     = {https://example.org},
  urldate = {2021-10-01},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{rfc4025} and \cite{corporate}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```